# how to use if condition in text field that the empty bubble doesn't go

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a **if condition** in my text field that if my text field is empty and send button is clicked the empty bubble shouldn't go.

```
 function typo(){
  var currentText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var x = '<div><p class=bubble>' + document.getElementById("myText").value + '</p></div>';
  document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
  var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText + x;

  var z = document.getElementById('demo');
  z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;
  document.getElementById("myText").focus();
  }

   <input class="widebox" type="text" id="myText" value="">
   <button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
```

This is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kkjbryqe/8/) for what am been trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `length` of the value.

```js
function typo() {
  if (document.getElementById("myText").value.length == 0) {
    // give error message
  } else {
    var currentText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var x = '<div><p class=bubble>' + document.getElementById("myText").value + '</p></div>';
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
    var y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText + x;

    var z = document.getElementById('demo');
    z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;
    document.getElementById("myText").focus();

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you can't copy and paste this code in your own... than you should probably seek for a professional scripter.

Comment: Thanks for the source !

Comment: Use the trim function to remove spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this :

if ( document.getElementById("Textfield").value)
{the code that sends the content}

And if you are adding this in a .html file just enclose the code in the script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kkjbryqe/35/

```
function typo(){
var x,y,x;
var currentText = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var ans = document.getElementById("myText").value;
var val = ans.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');

if(val === ""){

}
else{
    x = '<div><p class=bubble>' + 
    document.getElementById("myText").value + '</p></div>';
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
    y = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currentText + x;
    z = document.getElementById('demo');
    z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;
}
```

}

Comment: i just used some space and clicked the send button..the empty bubble still goes.

Comment: var val = ans.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, ''); i have added this line to check if it has whitespaces or not